# Reliably replace Newlines

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a (.Net) string which contains a variation of LFCR, CR, LF and CRLF newlines and I want to replace the earlier three with one CRLF but leave existing CRLFs untouched.

Basically what I want is a way to find '\n\r', '\n' and '\r' and replace them with one '\r\n' each but make sure each of those do not match/replace proper '\r\n' (CRLF) or replace a '\n\r' with two '\r\n'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Negative Lookahead, Negative Lookbehind**

I would suggest this:

```
\n?\r(?!\n)|(?<!\r)\n
```

- On the left side of the alternation '|', `\n?\r(?!\n)` matches `\n\r` or `\r`, but only if the negative lookahead `(?!\n)` is able to assert that what follows is not a `\r`
- On the right side, `(?<!\r)\n` matches all `\n` that are not preceded by `\r`

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Nice - thanks! And thanks for the reference links re: lookahead/-behind.. already used it in another usecase, too